# Select2 dropdown is not adding classes to its dropdown items from original options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Select2 is not adding the classes to its dropdown items from the options

Suppose in the below dropdown code, attribute class="highlight" was added to few options to highlight those with some background color. But select2 is not adding this class="highlight" to list items in dropdown

See the difference in below images.

Normal dropdown (cities1)

[image]

Select2 dropdown (cities2)

[image]

is it possible to get the same class names from options to select2 dropdown items?

Please help

```js
$('#cities2').select2();
```

```css
.highlight {
   background-color: #FFCCCB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="cities1">
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="3" class="highlight" >San Diego</option>
  <option value="4">Miami</option>
  <option value="5" class="highlight">Cambridge</option>
</select>

<select id="cities2">
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="3" class="highlight" >San Diego</option>
  <option value="4">Miami</option>
  <option value="5" class="highlight">Cambridge</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve but if you want to directly change the classes that `select2` generates you would have to do a small hack to the classes that the `select2` generates whenever the onchange event is triggered on the select element.

In other words, what I actually did was to target those two css classes that the `select2` generates whenever you hover or click on a certain option value. I applied a `!important` for the css style.

**EDIT:**

What I did in order to select and apply this certain css class to those specific options, I took the `templateResult` option from the documentation and added it whenevewr I trigger the `select2` plugin.
The `data.element` property has everything you need.  `.attr("class")` => gives you the `.highlight` class.

```
$(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
```

```js
 
     $("#cities1").select2({
          templateResult: function(data, container) {
            if (data.element) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log(container);

              $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
            }
            return data.text;
          }
       });

    $("#cities2").select2({
       templateResult: function(data, container) {
        if (data.element) {
          $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
        }
        return data.text;
       }
     });
```

```css
    .highlight {
       background-color: #FFCCCB;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="cities1">
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="3" class="highlight" >San Diego</option>
  <option value="4">Miami</option>
  <option value="5" class="highlight">Cambridge</option>
</select>

<select id="cities2">
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="3" class="highlight" >San Diego</option>
  <option value="4">Miami</option>
  <option value="5" class="highlight">Cambridge</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you Oris Sin. As per your suggestion, only selected item will be highlighted but my requirement is based on some other conditions few options will be highlighted using class attribute. But when the select2 dropdown is populating the class value "highlight" from original options is not adding to this select2 dropdown options

Comment: Please check my editted answer.